# What do I need rseq for, if I can do all the job using rpar?'

Tags: haskell, reactive-programming, future

I have the operation `x*x + 2*y` and I want to evaluate the left and right operands of the `+` concurrently.

My question is what is the difference between the following two implementations:

```hs
import Control.Parallel.Strategies

foo x y = runEval $ do
  left  <- rpar a
  right <- rpar b -- <==
  return $ left+right
  where a = x*x
        b = 2*y
```

```hs
import Control.Parallel.Strategies

foo x y = runEval $ do
  left  <- rpar a
  right <- rseq b -- <==
  return $ left+right
  where a = x*x
        b = 2*y
```

?
Which one do I need, and why?

I could ask the same about `par` and `pseq` ~~> I could do this:

```hs
import Control.Parallel

foo x y = a `par` b `par` a+b
  where a=x*x; b=2*y
```

instead of this:

```hs
import Control.Parallel

foo x y = a `par` b `pseq` a+b
  where a=x*x; b=2*y
```

Comment: I'm not 100% on this, but I think the idea is that if you use `pseq`, you guarantee that you won't duplicate the work by having both threads try to force the thunk at the same moment (because one thread will definitely be done by the time the other starts).

Answer (score 4):

`` a `par` b `par` a+b `` sparks `a`, then sparks `b`, then forces `a+b` which forces `a` and `b` in some arbitrary order. In an ideal scenario, the sparks will already be forcing `a` and `b`, in which case the forcing of `a+b` is suspended waiting for the computations to finish. However there is a subtle race condition, when a thunk is just about to be forced, and another thread starts forcing it at the same time, then they will both run the same computation redundantly, and race each other to write their results over the thunk, which should be the same thanks to purity hence why this race condition is tolerated in GHC's runtime.

`` a `par` b `pseq` a+b `` sparks `a`, then forces `b`, and finally forces `a+b`. If `b` runs for long enough, that gives the opportunity for the spark of `a` to fire before `a+b` gets forced, avoiding the aforementioned race condition.